# Insert foriegn keys from different tables to one table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm taking data from Excel file to Stagingtable using SSIS and I have 8 different Tables. From StagingTable I'm inserting data to different tables.
Now i have one table which consist of some data from Staging table plus I need to insert Foreign keys of all other table into this table(acts like a fact table).
I'm able to populate data into all the tables but I'm not able to populate the Foreign keys of all the tables into the fact table. 
How do i get the Foreign keys and insert it?

I'm expecting to insert the foreign keys into the fact table.

Answer (score 0):

Populate the dimension tables first so that foreign keys will be generated, and then join to them on the key-values while populating the fact table to get the foreign keys.

For example if you are importing an employee named John Smith from your Excel source, first insert John Smith into the Employee table.

Then when you are inserting John Smith into the fact table, join to the Employee table on EmployeeName='John Smith' to get his EmployeeID to insert into the fact table.

Comment: The data which I add into the dimension table will not be again inserted into the fact table. Example, if I'm inserting Contact of employees in Contact table than I won't have name or I'd of the employees in the contact table, it will just have the data but nobody knows which is corresponds to. Now when I add employee name into the fact table , along with the name I need the foreign key of contact which corresponds to the particular employee.

Comment: I don't see how what you're describing can possibly exist.   Please edit your question and give a visual example of what you're trying to describe.